# Parallax effect based on image position

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm still working on a Parallax website for a client based around 3 levels. I've encountered a problem that makes it impossible for me to add in the third top level.

The site itself has a full screen background that scrolls at one speed. Its a very long vertical image scrolling slowly. On top of that is the content which scrolls at the standard speed.

The third level is simply position: absolute graphics that sit on top of certain content areas. Floating images basically.

The problem I'm having is that with the majority of parallax plugins I've tried the floating third level images don't have anything to disappear behind. Meaning while I can set them based on the screen size as soon as I change it, I see it disappearing behind an invisible line.

Are there any plugins or methods I can use to stop this happening? So essentially I want to set a position where the image would be, if the parallax effect wasn't working, and it parallaxs around that point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own code, based on pure jquery/javascript.

Plugins are created for simple operations. 
You need to create JS application based on current `$(document).scrollTop()`

And main code pattern will be:

```
$(window).on('scroll resize',function(){
  var Top = $(document).scrollTop();
  if(Top < 200){ /*slide1 actions*/ }
  else if(Top >= 200 && Top < 400){ /*slide2 actions*/ }
  else if(Top >= 400 && Top < 600){ /*slide3 actions*/ }
  // etc
});
```

Also use this tips https://stackoverflow.com/a/11709360/1136141 for more performance

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I'm having is that with the majority of parallax plugins I've tried the floating third level images don't have anything to disappear behind.

Is the issue that you do want the third level images to disappear at certain points? I had a similar issue with a long single scrolling background, then constructed a page of divs on top of that, with no backgrounds, then placed the images in the various divs up and down the page with the div `overflow` set to `hidden`. Made for easier placement of the third-level images, and also meant you could hide them at specific points.

Answer (score 0):

if you can get it working on screen size just use jquery to get and set object position based on screen size,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery.event.add(window, "load", resizeFrame);
    jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);

    function resizeFrame() 

    {
        var h = $(window).height();

        $('#foo1') .css({'top': (h-30)});
        $('#foo2') .css({'left': (h-67)});

    }
});
```

for example.